# Choose data from the most recent two years for out of sample testing

Tags: forecasting, cross-validation

I have a dataset that contains monthly data for the past four decades. I understand that if I use 5-fold cross validation, I need to randomly pick training set and testing set. Can I use data from the most recent two years as the testing set? If so, how should I revise the procedure? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, since standard CV doesn't work for time series data. See:
https://www.otexts.org/fpp2/accuracy.html